# "detailedMessage":"Operation failed due to conflicting concurrent operations (please retry), 0 transactions are currently rolling back

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, request, amazon-neptune, opencypher

The Load operation on Neptune failed due to the deletion of files from s3 in between the s3 to Neptune load. Since then I am able to delete all the relationships that are present between nodes through opencypher query but unable to delete nodes.

gets error **{"detailedMessage":"Operation failed due to conflicting concurrent operations (please retry), 0 transactions are currently rolling back.","code":"ConcurrentModificationException"** even after retrying many times.

The query used for deleting all nodes is `query=MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r`

Comment: Do you actually have any edges/relationships left in the graph? Does the CME also also happen if you do `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n` ? Which Amazon Neptune engine version are you using? How many nodes are currently in the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved adding limit to the query ***"MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT 100000 DETACH DELETE n"*** . Running this query in recursive solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that query is attempting to drop the entire graph.  An easier way to do that with Neptune is to use the Fast Reset API.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/manage-console-fast-reset.html

This feature is also available via a Neptune Notebook by using the `%db_reset` Jupyter magic.

This will delete everything within a couple of seconds by resetting the cluster back to its original empty state.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful in resolving this but it will also delete the other data formats(RDF data) which could be conflicting.